# Building mavros failed (Having tried three ways)

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, mavros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have tried to build the recent mavros package from its [source](https://github.com/mavlink/mavros).  I have tried three different ways; they all failed.  My OS is Ubutnu 16.04.03 LTS (xenial).

Can anyone let me know the right way to compile the package?

### First try

```
$ git clone https://github.com/mavlink/mavros.git mavros_recent

$ catkin_make -DCATKIN_WHITELIST_PACKAGES="mavros_recent"
```

The compilation does not work, with the following message produced:

```
Multiple packages found with the same name "libmavconn":
- mavros/libmavconn
- mavros_recent/libmavconn
Multiple packages found with the same name "mavros":
- mavros/mavros
- mavros_recent/mavros
```

### Second try

Then, I tried a more direct way.

```
$ cd src/mavros_recent/mavros/
$ mkdir build; cd build; cmake ..
```

I got an error from CMake

```
-- Could not find the required component 'geographic_msgs'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "geographic_msgs"
  with any of the following names:

    geographic_msgsConfig.cmake
    geographic_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "geographic_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "geographic_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.
  If "geographic_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be
  sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

### Third try

According to [a ROS official page](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep)

> You can use rosdep and catkin to build
> any package in the ROS repository. Say
> that you want to build a package
> called AMAZING_PACKAGE, that you
> hadn't built on your machine before.
>
> rosdep install AMAZING_PACKAGE

In my case, the amazing_package is mavros. It seems rosdep does not recognize mavros as a package, as shown from the error message below:

```
$rosdep install mavros

ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource mavros
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share
```

So, what's the right way to build it from source?

[EDIT] I would like to build *from source*, instead of use apt-get, because eventually I will need to build mavros of a special commiit hash.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285658/building-mavros-failed-(having-tried-three-ways)/) by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 186 on 2018-03-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-16**:
You didn't say what your OS is, but assuming you're using Ubuntu 16.04 did you try

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-mavros ros-kinetic-mavros-extras
```

instead of building it?

**Comment by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) on 2018-03-17**:
Thanks and it is good to know the apt-get way. However, I would like to build from source instead of use apt-get, because eventually I will need to build mavros of a special commiit hash.

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2018-03-20**:
Maybe try reading [documentation](https://github.com/mavlink/mavros/blob/master/mavros/README.md#installation) first next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
for installing geographic go to mavros/scripts and type ./install_geographiclib_datasets.sh in your terminal

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2018-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) on 2018-03-17**:
Thanks. But that gives me another error: scripts/install_geographiclib_datasets.sh: line 27: hash: geographiclib-get-geoids: not found

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2018-03-17**:
try

```
sudo apt-get install geographiclib-* ros-kinetic-geographic-*
```

then try again with scrip

**Comment by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) on 2018-03-19**:
After running the apt-get command above, and then the script you mentioned. catkin_make now gives me a new error "Could not find a package configuration file provided by "geographic_msgs" with any of the following names "geographic_msgsConfig.cmake, geographic_msgs-config.cmake"

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2018-03-19**:
try

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-geographic-msgs
```

and make again

**Comment by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) on 2018-03-19**:
With your suggested command, the Console responds: "ros-kinetic-geographic-msgs is already the newest version." Actually, if I ran "dpkg -l | grep geo ", I found ros-kinetic-geodesy, ros-kinetic-geographic-info, ros-kinetic-geographic-msgs, and ros-kinetic-geometry-msgs installed.

**Comment by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) on 2018-03-20**:
Finally, it works!